# MongoDB Atlas Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, transactions, devops

I am using MongoDB as my primary database with the Mongoose ODM. I am dealing with some database transactions and the only way to do achieve DB Transactions in MongoDB is to use `replicaSets`. I was able to achieve this in development mode using the `run-rs` package. However, in production mode, from the MongoDB docs using replicaSets requires that I set up k8s object with Atlas. But I am just a beginner at containers and orchestration. I tried learning about Docker, is it possible to setup a service that could run this replicaSets from docker? And is there any easier way I could setup replicaSets with MongoDB Atlas?

Thanks.

Comment: All instances of MongoDB Atlas clusters are replica sets. You do not need k8s to use them. Where in the docs did you read that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a one node replica set for development and testing.